# iCal4j parse meeting request from ICS

Tags: java, icalendar, ical4j

I want to parse ics files received from an Exchange using `iCal4j` to create a `VEvent` for local processing, and modify them to create a new time proposal (`COUNTER` method) for sending them back to the Exchange.
The problem is that I was only able to build `Calendar` objects (see the code below), no `VEvent`.

```
File file = new File(PATH);
CalendarBuilder builder = new CalendarBuilder();
net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar cal = null;
try {
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    cal = builder.build(fis);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Most probably, I would be able to create the replies from scratch, but if I could create them from the invite directly, I guess the result would be more likely to work. Also, I really would like to avoid parsing the files manually and hack around with string matching and things like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the solution is rather simple, it is just not detailed in the examples of iCal4j, where I was looking for help. (Sorry, I am a novice programmer). But after looking into the [API reference of iCal4j](http://m2.modularity.net.au/projects/ical4j/apidocs/), I found the following:

If you parse an ics file to a `Calendar` object, it will have only a few `Properties`, like `METHOD`, `PRODID` and `VERSION` in our case. But it might (and most probably will) have some [Components](http://m2.modularity.net.au/projects/ical4j/apidocs/net/fortuna/ical4j/model/Component.html) too, like `VEvent`, `VTodo`, etc, which is the actual content of the ics file. You can get the Components' list with

```
ComponentList cl = cal.getComponents();
```

For us, parsing, modifying and sending them will be much easier than creating them from scratch.